# Excel VBA Combobox list in Module have selection then output to cell

Tags: excel, vba

Cant seem to find the answer to this, I need a combobox (which is inside a userform) that has three selection
eg Rental,Purchase and Finance

Which the selected input is then put into example cell A1. I know how to do this if I have the list already on my excel sheet, but I don't want the list on the excel sheet only the selection. so I suppose I'm asking for a coded list of option inside the module which then outputs the result in to a cell.

Any help would be appreciated (I'm a Newbie)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic code in the userform:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   If me.combobox1.listindex > -1 then sheets("Sheet name").Range("A1").value = me.combobox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Rental", "Purchase", "Finance")
End Sub
```

Comment: with it been descriptions and not numbers I was a little unsure but that worked like a charm, thanks again Rory, sorry for the newbie questions

Comment: How do I get the selection to stay in the form if the form is close and then reopened, I tried using Me.Combobox1.List = CStr(Range("B10").Value) Which Didn't work

Comment: You want `Me.Combobox1.Value` rather than List

Comment: Thanks again Rory. your a true guru